# UITableView insert row breaks scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, tableview

I am trying to insert row at the top of the table. Firstly insert into the data:

```
[self.myDataArray insertObject:scannedItem atIndex:0];
```

Then I call reloadData for the table. Item inserted but table scrolls up, item doesn't visible and it is possible to scroll all items out of the top bound. I have no dynamic cells and also have estimatedRowHeight set as const integer(60).

Here is screens for tableview

[image]
[image]

Comment: `tableView` has a function `insertRowAtIndexPath:` don't reload the `tableView`.

Comment: the same effect

Comment: Show screenshot of `tableView`

Comment: Added screens two screens

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.myDataArray insertObject:scannedItem atIndex:0];
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath inSection:0]]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```